# Dymo label Writer

Tags: print, node.js, streaming

Привет!

Сейчас стоит задача, заставить печатать принтер лейблов (Dymo label writer 450 turbo) в node.js приложении. 
В Node.js не силен

Вот код:

```
// https://github.com/churchio/checkin-printer

var stream = require('stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var lpr = spawn('lpr', [], {stdin: 'pipe'});
var readable = new stream.Readable(true);
readable._read = function noop() {}; // See note below
readable.push('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips"><PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation><Id>ReturnAddressInt</Id><PaperName>11352 Return Address Int</PaperName><DrawCommands><RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1440" Height="3060" Rx="180" Ry="180"/></DrawCommands><ObjectInfo><TextObject><Name>Sativa</Name><ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/><BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255"/><LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName><Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation><IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored><IsVariable>False</IsVariable><HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment><VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment><TextFitMode>ShrinkToFit</TextFitMode><UseFullFontHeight>True</UseFullFontHeight><Verticalized>False</Verticalized><StyledText><Element><String>SATIVA</String><Attributes><Font Family="Helvetica" Size="18" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/><ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/></Attributes></Element></StyledText></TextObject><Bounds X="129.5999" Y="57.59995" Width="2846.4" Height="541.25"/></ObjectInfo><ObjectInfo><BarcodeObject><Name>BARCODE</Name><ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/><BackColor Alpha="255" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255"/><LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName><Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation><IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored><IsVariable>False</IsVariable><Text>100000</Text><Type>Code39</Type><Size>Medium</Size><TextPosition>Bottom</TextPosition><TextFont Family="Helvetica" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/><CheckSumFont Family="Helvetica" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/><TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding><ECLevel>0</ECLevel><HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment><QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Right="0" Top="0" Bottom="0"/></BarcodeObject><Bounds X="129.5999" Y="572.4624" Width="2846.4" Height="785.9375"/></ObjectInfo></DieCutLabel>');

readable.push('.\r\n');
readable.push(null);

/**
 * Pipe our readable stream into wc's standard input.
 */
readable.pipe(lpr.stdin);
```

Если я передаю на печать XML код, то печатается белый листик (`readable.push('<?xml version="1.0"...`)

Если передать не XML, то все ок, печать выполняется нормально. Но мне нужно печатать карточки в XML формате

**Почему именно XML разметка?**

Есть приложение Dymo Label Writer. Там можно создать карточку, и она сохраняется в формате .label. Но внутри этого файла, обычная XML разметка

**Вопрос**

Как заставить принтер печатать XML карточки?

Comment: возможно ваше приложение (writer которое) прежде чем выполнить печать все таки приводит xml к "читабельному" виду - т.е. применяет данные на шаблон и получает готовую страницу. Получается нужно перед отдачей принтеру пропустить ваш xml через шаблон xsl например и отдать результат на принтер

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы клонировать вопрос, лучше бы внесли правки в предыдущий.

Comment: Может. Я не знаю. Могли бы мне помочь разобратся в даном вопросе?